# How should I assign a notification channel to my existing Firebase notification class?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using Firebase, I send notifications to my app and open certain activity from the click-action of the notification data. The problem is, it works fine where API level is <26. But as for the new versions, all notifications must be assigned to a channel. But I'm not sure how I can assign my existing system with a channel that works on API level 26 or higher?

This is my `FirebaseMessagingService` java class:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingServic";

    public FirebaseMessagingService() {}

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
                String jsonMessage = data.getString("extra_information");
                Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: \n" +
                    "Extra Information: " + jsonMessage);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(); //get title
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(); //get message
            String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction(); //get click_action

            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Title: " + title);
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + message);
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification click_action: " + click_action);

            sendNotification(title, message, click_action);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {

    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, String click_action) {
        Intent intent;
        if (click_action.equals("SOMEACTIVITY")) {
            intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */ , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */ , notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I'm really curious what should I change here to assign it to a channel?

I'm also sharing my `ActivityMain` activity and Manifest xml below:

```
public class MainActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("DAILYDOSE");
    }

}
```

And the manifest:

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity android:name=".SomeActivity">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="SOMEACTIVITY" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
   </service>
   <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
      android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a channel you will need to create a channelId before creating the notification. You could create the channel ID when the service is created, e.g.

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "default";
    private static final String CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION = "Your description...";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to use the channel ID when creating your Notification, i.e.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But should I need to update the `FirebaseMessagingService` java class only or anything else? It would be really helpful if you could update how I could fit the channel in the `FirebaseMessagingService`

Comment: If the only place you're creating notifications is within FirebaseMessagingService then that should be the only place you need to create the Channel ID and assign it via the NotificationCompat.Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an existing notification channel with its original values performs no operation, so it's safe to call this code when starting an app.
This is where it's all explained https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannel.

What's important is the channelId, that needs to be consistent in all calls: in channel creation and as parameter to NotificationCompat.Builder().